# Unable to bind (bad bind) values in Oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am creating trigger in which I need to create logs for that table in separate table. Trigger runs when insert or update, and add values by column name with values, following is script;

this gives me an error of unable to bind values

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TABLE_TRGGER
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON MY_TABLE
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   FOR R IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
               FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
              WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE')
   LOOP
      IF UPDATING (R.COLUMN_NAME)
      THEN
         INSERT INTO MY_LOGS_TABLE (COLUMN_NAME,
                                    CREATED_BY,
                                    CREATED_ON,
                                    CURRENT_COL_VALUE,
                                    OLD_COL_VALUE,
                                    TABLE_NAME,
                                    UPDATED_BY,
                                    UPDATED_ON)
              VALUES ('' || R.COLUMN_NAME || '' , /* COLUMN name as string */,
                      :NEW.CREATED_BY ,
                      :NEW.CREATED_ON,
                      :NEW.R.COLUMN_NAME /* UNABLE TO BIND THIS VALUE */,
        :OLD.R.COLUMN_NAME/* UNABLE TO BIND THIS VALUE */,
        ''|| R.TABLE_NAME ||'' ,/* TABLE name as string */
        :NEW.UPDATED_BY,
        :NEW.UPDATED_ON );
       END IF;
    END LOOP;
END MY_TABLE_TRGGER;
```

Comment: You can't do it. All column names must be specified explicitly.

Comment: I am getting the column name then Why I can't do that ?

Comment: There is no way you can access the `:new` and `:old` bind values for dynamic column names. It can only access defined column names specified during compilation.

Comment: I want to do this for only columns which are being updated, I am not sure which column will be updated. Then How would I do that ? Can you please help me regarding this.

Comment: You have to explicitly compare the old and new values of all the columns of the table and insert entries for those which have changed.Also nulls must be handled appropriately

Comment: *"I want to do this for only columns which are being updated, "* This is an audit anti-pattern. Store the new row, it makes it easier to recover the audit trail - which should be the object of the exercise.